# How do I generate code from an xcore model during a gradle build

Tags: gradle, xtext, xcore

So I am attempting to build my project in a build server. My dsl's are failing to build because they rely on code from my xcore model and the generated code from the xcore model is not in the repository the build server pulls from. I am unsure what actually kicks off the the code generation on the xcore model. So how can I ensure that the model code is generated before gradle attempts to build my other dsl's?

Attached build.gradle for xcore project:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
  xtextTooling.extendsFrom xcore // alias xtextTooling to xcore to prevent confusion
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0"
    testRuntime "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0"
    testCompile "org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext.testing:${xtextVersion}"

    compile "org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext:${xtextVersion}"
    compile "org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext.xbase:${xtextVersion}"
    compile 'org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xcore.lib:+'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.xtext', name: 'org.eclipse.xtext.ecore', version: '2.15.0'

    xcore group: 'org.eclipse.emf', name: 'org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.lib', version: '2.9.1.201705291010'
    xcore group: 'org.eclipse.emf', name: 'org.eclipse.emf.codegen', version: '2.14.0'

    xcore 'org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore:+'
    xcore 'org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.xtext:+'
    xcore 'org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xcore:1.3.1'
    xcore 'org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xcore.lib:+'
    xcore "org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext.ecore:${xtextVersion}"

}

xtext {
    version = "${xtextVersion}"
    languages {
        ecore {
            setup = 'org.eclipse.xtext.ecore.EcoreSupport'
        }
        codegen {
            setup = 'org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.xtext.GenModelSupport'
        }
        xcore {
            setup = 'org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xcore.XcoreStandaloneSetup'
            generator.outlet.producesJava = true
        }

    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            exclude '**/*.xcore'
        }
        java {
            srcDir 'build/xcore/main'
        }
    }
}

clean {
    delete 'build/xcore/main'
}
```

I saw some examples with a slightly different xtext region:

```
xtext {
    version = "${xtextVersion}"
    languages {
        ecore {
            setup = 'org.eclipse.xtext.ecore.EcoreSupport'
        }
        codegen {
            setup = 'org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.xtext.GenModelSupport'
        }
        xcore {
            setup = 'org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xcore.XcoreStandaloneSetup'
            generator.outlet.producesJava = true
            output {
                dir 'build/xcore/main'
                producesJavaFor sourceSets.main
            }
        }

    }
}
```

but if I attempt to use this I get the gradle error:

> Could not find method output() for arguments
>   [build_..._run_closure...] on object of type
>   org.xtext.gradle.tasks.Language

Comment: Did you examine https://github.com/ghillairet/xcore-gradle-example

Comment: The plugin docs contain a sample for the generator section http://xtext.github.io/xtext-gradle-plugin/xtext-builder.html

Comment: Yea I looked over those but have not been able to figure anything out. Okay now I think I realize all of that output stuff is just related to generating code while your editing the xcore file. Which works fine. But how would I go about generating all that code during a gradle build? something like a `build { dependsOn(generateModelCode) }`

Comment: I don’t understand what usecase. Can you please elaborate

Comment: Here is another sample https://github.com/itemis/itemis-blog/tree/xcore_gradle

Comment: They all generate Java from xcore

Comment: So I am trying to keep my generated code out of the remote repository. Thus I want to only have the .xcore file. But I have a few dsl's that depend on the .xcores package. So on the remote build server the issue I am running into is that my other languages fail to build because they cannot find the generated classes from the .xcore file.

Comment: I replicated this locally by deleting my generated code directory and attempt a build. Which failed because it did not regen the code when it built

Comment: Then you do something wrong. Have a look at the link i pasted right before

Comment: That link is the one I originally viewed for setting everything up. (Which was very helpful) But so I understand, given a configuration like the one in the link it is expected that the xcore model should generate its java code on a gradle build? If that's the case, then maybe my setup is correct and the issue is coming from somwhere else

Comment: i updated the example https://github.com/itemis/itemis-blog/tree/xcore_gradle_upgrade_xtext_neu 8 month ago and will give it a try now

Comment: Alright, I am going to try and dig into my gradle setup and build server setup more.

Comment: the main problem is maven/gradle dependency hell and to find a working combination

Comment: Well, I was hoping it was a path issue in the build server, but it all looks good, it's just that there is no generated code from the xcore model. Do you have a process you would recommend for dependency hell?

Comment: no just try. but i see another issue with clean vs generateXtext and gradle thinking nothing to be done. this could be a bug as well

Comment: I pulled down that github example to try and replicate, but it appears to have its own dependency issues. I'm going to try and get it working and see if I can replicate the issue. Unfortunately i'm going to be gone for the next couple of days. But will update as soon as i'm back.

Comment: updated the sample. build twice issue is still there

Comment: https://github.com/xtext/xtext-gradle-plugin/issues/139

Comment: I got the example project up and running with the issue. Would you like to continue this in the 139 issue thread?